# Shortcode with multiple meta_key attributes

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, acfpro, meta-query

I added two custom fields: day (event_day) & month (event_month) (both of type radio) for CPT Events. Now i want to be able to get posts by meta_key day and month.

The shortcode works except the part with $meta_query.

Here is how shorеcode should look like :
[tribe_custom_events_list_mm_wed cat="Rodrigo" num="6" day="Monday" month="October"]

Bellow is the code responsible for the shortcode, added in functions.php

```
function tribe_custom_events_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{

  global $post;

  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'cat'     => '',
    'num'     => '',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
    'field'   => 'name',
    'day'   => '',
    'month' => '',
  ), $atts));

  $tax_query = array(
      'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
      'field'    => $field,
      'terms'    => $cat,
  );

  $day = $day;
  $month = $month;

  $meta_query = array(
    array(
      'key'   => 'event_day',
      'value' => '$day',
      'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
      'key'   => 'event_month',
      'value' => '$month',
      'compare' => '='
    ),
  );

  $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'order'          => $order,
    'orderby'        => $orderby,
    'tax_query' => array($tax_query),
    'meta_query' => array($meta_query),
  );

  $output = '';

  $posts = get_posts($args);

  foreach ($posts as $post) {

    setup_postdata($post);

    $output .= '<div class="tribe-mini-calendar-event event-0  first  last">';
    $output .= '<h4 class="tribe-events-title"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>';
    $output .= '</div>';
  }

  echo '<pre>' , var_dump($meta_query) , '</pre>';

  wp_reset_postdata();

  return '<div>' . $output  . '</br>' . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('tribe_custom_events_list_mm_wed', 'tribe_custom_events_shortcode');
```

Comment: array($tax_query) since you're declaring in correct format, it looks as though you've got an extra array here.

Comment: @HowardE E - Hi, i updated my code. Indeed there was an extra array. I removed it but still no posts are shown.

Comment: And your meta_query. I assumed you would have picked up on that when you looked at the other thing.

Comment: @HowardE - changed my code like this : 
`
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'order'          => $order,
    'orderby'        => $orderby,
    'tax_query' => array($tax_query),
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key'   => 'event_day',
        'value' => '$day',
        'compare' => '='
      ),
      array(
        'key'   => 'event_month',
        'value' => '$month',
        'compare' => '='
      ),
    ),
  );
`

OR relation works https://prnt.sc/1wep0tz .

Comment: Does not work properly with OR relation. Weird, i set the shortcode parameter to Monday and posts that have different value still are shown. Even if none of meta keys respect the rule, posts are still being displayed....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.  There were a few errors in your code... Noted in the comments below.

```
$tax_query = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'field'    => $field,
    'terms'    => $cat,
);

/* This is unnecessary since $day already = $day
  $day = $day;
  $month = $month;
*/

$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key'   => 'event_day',
        'value' => $day, // Don't put quotes around variables
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key'   => 'event_month',
        'value' => $month,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
);

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'order'          => $order,
    'orderby'        => $orderby,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query, // This is already an array defined above
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
);
```

Comment: Thank you ! Silly mistake from me. It now works.